# Using Notification.image or Notification.icon

Tags: javascript, web-push, browser-feature-detection, web-notifications

I'm working on deploying web push for notifications. Everything is working great, but I've come to understand that some browsers do not support `Notification.image`, or at least do not display said image. However, they all do seem to support `Notification.icon`, and Firefox actually uses `Notification.icon` to display an image in their rich push example.

I would ideally like to use `Notification.image` when supported, but fallback to `Notification.icon` when not. However, it's not so simple as just supplying an image for both, as then on browsers that do support displaying `Notification.image`, you'll get it twice.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to detect support. Unfortunately, even browsers that don't support display still know that `Notification.image` is a thing that exists, so basic feature detection is out. I'd also like to avoid UA detection if at all possible, as keeping up with supported UAs would likely be a nightmare. Anyone know of anything I'm missing, or how have you handled this in your own experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. Well, now I feel stupid. Ah well, that's how we learn. Turns out, you can feature detect. I made an assumption that since `Notification.image` was in MDN, that Firefox at least would know about it, even though it is one of the browsers in particular that does not support displaying it. Then, I came across [this actually very helpful site](https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/demos/notification-examples/), and noticed that the buttons were greyed out if the particular section is not supported in your browser. The "Image" button was greyed out, so there must be a way to detect support, and after digging in the site's source, I face-palmed:

```
'image' in Notification.prototype
```

So, yes, it really is that simple. At least this might help someone else find the answer quicker.